# how to download binary image from database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, binary

I have stored image in db as binary format. While click on link button I want to download that image. Help me to find a proper solution. Thank you.

Code:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   if (!IsPostBack)
     {

      pdfDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_imgTableAdapter td;
      td = new pdfDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_imgTableAdapter();
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      dt = td.GetId();        //Sql1
      DropDownList1.DataSource = dt;
      DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Id";
      DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Id";
      DropDownList1.DataBind();
      DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("--Select Id--", ""));
     }

  }
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     pdfDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_imgTableAdapter td;
     td = new pdfDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_imgTableAdapter();
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     dt = td.GetImg(int.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue));   //Sql2
     foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
      {
         byte[] img2 = (byte[])row["img"];
         string base2 = Convert.ToBase64String(img2);
         Image1.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpg;base64," + base2;
       }     
   }

protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      // image download
   }
```

Sql1:

```
SELECT Id FROM tbl_img
```

Sql2:

```
SELECT img FROM tbl_img WHERE (Id = @Id)
```

aspx:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"> </asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Show" />
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">Download</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
```

DB:

[image]
[image]

O/P Screen:

[image]

Comment: -1 for asking the same question 3 times.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26862880/745969) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26901297/745969).

Answer (score 1):

As of less time now, I am suggesting you a link. Follow the steps mentioned in it. It will surely help  you.

[Downloading files doc](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Upload-and-Download-files-from-SQL-Server-Database-in-ASPNet.aspx)